Google Calendar API keep returning 400 bad request
my code:
import os
import json

import dotenv
import requests
import requests_oauthlib


class Calendar():
    def __init__(self):
        dotenv.load_dotenv()

        self.api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")
        self.calendar_id = os.getenv("CALENDAR_ID")
        self.access_token = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_ACCESS_TOKEN")

    def auth(self, scopes):
        with open("./assets/credentials.json", "r") as json_file:
            credentials = json.load(json_file)

            client_id = credentials["web"]["client_id"]
            client_secret = credentials["web"]["client_secret"]
            redirect_uri = credentials["web"]["redirect_uris"][0]
            authorization_url = credentials["web"]["auth_uri"]
            token_url = credentials["web"]["token_uri"]

        scopes = scopes

        with requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(client_id=client_id, scope=scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_uri) as session:
            authorization_url, state = session.authorization_url(authorization_url, access_type="offline", prompt="select_account")
            print("click the link to auth", authorization_url)

        redirect_response = input("Paste the redirect URL here:")
        credentials = session.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=redirect_response)

        dotenv.set_key(".env", key_to_set="GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_ACCESS_TOKEN", value_to_set=credentials["access_token"], quote_mode="never")
        self.access_token = credentials["access_token"]

    def add_event(self, summary, start_date, end_date, description="", recurrence=False):
        url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{self.calendar_id}/events"

        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.access_token}",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
       
        payload = {
            "end": {
                "dateTime": end_date,
                "timeZone": "Asia/Taipei"
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": start_date,
                "timeZone": "Asia/Taipei"
            }
        }

        if recurrence:
            payload["recurrence"] = ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY"]

        response = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, headers=headers)

        return response.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Calendar()
    c.auth(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"])
    print(c.add_event(summary="test", start_date="2024-09-05T01:00:00.000", end_date="2024-09-17T13:00:00.000"))

output:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}

I have try the API on Google's APIs Explorer, and it successfully added event to calendar. However, when I do the same thing in python, it got wrong.
At the beginning, I thoght it's because the "datetime" format, but I have try many different format, and all of them return the same "400 bad request".

I thought that in the case of "Events: insert" of Calendar API, the request body is required to be a string converted from JSON. So, how about the following modification?
From:
response = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, headers=headers)

To:
response = requests.post(url=url, json=payload, headers=headers)

or
response = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

Note:

When I tested the script reflected in this modification, I confirmed that an event could be created without the error of Bad Request.

Reference:

Events: insert


thank you very much, it works perfectly!!

@高奕祥 About thank you very much, it works perfectly!!, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
